# How can i upload image outside project folder Php Laravel?

Tags: laravel, file, upload, storage

I want to save uploaded file to '/home/user/images' folder.

Is there any way to do this?

My 1st try:
controller

```
public function save(Request $request) {
     $file = $request->file('image');
     $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     $file_path = '/home/user/images';
     
     $file->move($file_path, $file_name);
}
```

/////////////////////

My 2nd try:
filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [
..
'custom_folder' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => '/home/user/images',
 ],
...
```

controller

```
public function save(Request $request) {
     $file = $request->file('image');,
     $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     
     Storage::disk('custom_folder')->put($file_name, $file);
}
```

I'm sorry if there is anything I did wrong. I just started learning php and Laravel.
For now, I save the files in the 'public / images' file path. I will use these files in multiple projects in the future. So I thought of such a method but could not reach the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
  $image = $request->image;
  $image_new_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
  $image->move('storage/custom_folder/', $image_new_name);
}
```

"storage" folder can be found inside "public" folder; public/storage/custom_folder.

If you want it outside your server dir then create a symlink inside your project folder.